# Event on drop on fullcalendar send automaticlly to the date slot that holds that particular data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

can someone please help me with this I am stuck and I need your help.. :/
So my problem is this:
I have on the left side the events(appointments) which contain data like(title and datetime) what I need is when I drag the event and drop on the calendar this event holds the data info I want that to automaticlly go to that date slot, so to be pulled to that date slot even though i dropp it somwhere else.

So this is my code:

```
<div id='external-events'>
  @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
    <div class='fc-event {{ $colors[array_rand($colors)] }}' apo_id="{{$appointment->id}}"  >  
        {{$appointment->firstname}}  <br>{{$appointment->start_at}}</div><br>    
     @endforeach
    <p>
        <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' checked/>
        <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
        <?php $i=1; ?>
 @foreach($agents as $key=> $agent)
    <div class="tab-pane agent tabs{{$key}}" id="agent{{$agent->id}}"  agent_id="{{$agent->id}}"   role="tabpanel">

               <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">

                    <div id='calendar-container'>
                        <div id='calendar{{$agent->id}}' class="calendar" agent-id="{{{$agent->id}}}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
    </div>
```

And here I have my js:

```
<script src="{{ asset('app/assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var appointments = <?php  echo json_encode($appointments_agents) ?>;
       console.log(appointments);


$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var agent_id = $(e.target).attr("agent_idja") 


  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    $(this).data('event', {

      title: $.trim($(this).text()), 
      stick: true 
    });


    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,  
      revertDuration: 0  
    });

  });
  var getEvent = []; 
  for(i=0; i<appointments.length; i++)

  if(appointments[i]['agent_id'] == agent_id){

  var firstname =  appointments[i]['firstname'];
  var start_at  = appointments[i]['start_at'];

color1 = '#000',
color2 = '#ef6e6e',
color3 = '#22c6ab',
color4 = 'yellow'

var colors = [color1,color2,color3, color4];
var colorss = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

    var insertEvents = {};
        insertEvents =
        {
            title: firstname,
            start: start_at,
            color  : colorss,
        }
    getEvent.push(insertEvents);
}

  $('#calendar' + agent_id).fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, 
       events: getEvent,
    drop: function(event) {
         var apo_id = $(this).attr('apo_id');
          console.log(agent_id);

            $.ajax({

                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('/change-agent') }}",
                data: {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    agent_id: agent_id,
                    appointment_id:apo_id
                },
                success: function () {

                  console.log("ok");

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });

      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {

        $(this).remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

So here I am using this js for showing events that are alreay assigned to an agent, and with ajax on drop to assign to that agent of that selected tab.
But as I explained the event wont be pulled to that particular slot. Can you please help..?

Comment: if you want the item to always go to an exact slot, why use drag and drop? You're implying to the user that they have freedom to choose where to place the item, when they don't. Instead you could just wait for the user to click the item (to indicate they wish to include it on the calendar) and then you can just use fullCalendar's renderEvent method to add it to the calendar in the location you've defined.

Comment: on this case the user is admin, and I have tabs of agents, admin changes tabs and therefore the calendar changes, I need it that way on drop to be pulled to that date that hold the item

Comment: Sorry I don't see why that would prevent you from using click instead of drag

Comment: The same even on click I don't know how it would be possible to show to the calendar, I am sorry if I am asking too much it just my first project and I am stressing so much

Comment: What I meant was that once the user has clicked your item you can use this method: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvent to add the data to fullCalendar as a new event.

Comment: I managed on drop to pull that date to that slot but it also adds the event to where I drop, so this means when I drop it drops two events the one where it should be(to that particular slot that holds the date) and the other one is where I let go to that slot. I tried putting on success  $('.fc-resizable').hide(); and this works but what I need is also make caledar slot to not be draggable any more, when I do editable:false, the  $('.fc-resizable').hide(); on success it does not work any more  is there any other way..? thank you very much

Comment: Like I said, why are you persisting with dragging? You don't need it for this purpose. The event always must always go into a fixed place, so dragging is a nonsense. Users will imagine they can place the event wherever they wish...but they cannot. Use a click instead!! If you're worried about making it go to the correct calendar...that's not so hard, it's always the one within the currently visible tab. I'm not sure about $('.fc-resizable').hide();, I'm not sure what you're referring to. You'd have to show the code and make it clearer what situation you're describing.

Comment: If I got it correct, just add an attribute (or class) to your external events which identifies the calendar they belong to. On `drop` event of each calendar check if the event belongs to this calendar, otherwise remove it otherwise let it render

Comment: can you provide me with an example please i dont understand how..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make event of full calendar on drop go to that slot of that date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729324/how-to-make-event-of-full-calendar-on-drop-go-to-that-slot-of-that-date)