# How to make event of full calendar on drop go to that slot of that date

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

Hi there Can you help me please, is it possible on drop of event if event has title :event1 and start_at:`10/10/2018`  when I drop this event to the calendar the event to be dropped automaticly to that slot of date even though I just drop it somewhere ele is it possible somehow to be pulled to that slot with date `10/10/2018`..?
Here is an example of fullcalendar drag drop

https://codepen.io/subodhghulaxe/pen/qEXLLr?editors=0010

Comment: you asked the same question a few days ago, and I already suggested to stop using drag and drop. If you want to place a specific event in a specific location then program your code to do that, instead of trying to change what the drag and drop does. The idea of drag and drop is to let the user choose where to put the event. If you don't want them to choose, then don't use drag and drop, it's simple. Just let the user click on this particular event outside the calendar. When they click on it, then you add the event to the calendar automatically in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is possible by adding your own logic as @ADyson mentioned above in comments.

**HTML**

Well, I have added `id` and `date` as an attribute to external events something like this:

```
<div class='fc-event' id='1' date='2018-10-13'>My Event 1</div>
<div class='fc-event' id='2' date='2018-10-09'>My Event 2</div>
<div class='fc-event' id='3' date='2018-10-14'>My Event 3</div>
<div class='fc-event' id='4' date='2018-10-04'>My Event 4</div>
<div class='fc-event' id='5' date='2018-10-27'>My Event 5</div>
```

**jQuery**

then, `id: $(this).attr('id')` for each external events

```
$(this).data('event', {
    id: $(this).attr('id'),
    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
});
```

and, at last I am creating a new event on the basis of particular date and removing the event before it by using `$(this).attr('id')` as you can see below:

```
drop: function(date) {              
    var newEvent = {
        title:$(this).text(),
        start: $(this).attr('date'),
        end: $(this).attr('date'),
        allDay: false
    };

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $(this).attr('id'));              
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);

    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

This is just an idea, so now you can change it as per your need. You can also use same logic on internal calendar events!

---

**Return external events back to the list by using external `div/button`**

Probably, this is not the best approach to revert external events back to the list from the calendar, but what I'm doing here is on clicking the external div `#back-to-list`, retrieving all events from FullCalendar memory and creating a `div` named **eventDiv** then appending it into `$('#external-events-listing')` and also adding `draggable` to events. Then, removing all events from the calendar.

```
$('#back-to-list').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {        
        var eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
        eventDiv.setAttribute("class", "fc-event");
        eventDiv.setAttribute("id", event.id);
        eventDiv.setAttribute("date", event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        eventDiv.innerText = event.title;

        $('#external-events-listing').append(eventDiv);

        $(eventDiv).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 0
        });
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
});
```

If external event has `editable: false` then dragging is not possible with in the calendar.

---

**Undo last event to the list**

Set `tempArray` globally, while adding a new event on drag in add event into `tempArray`, on `#undo-last-item` click retrieve event details from `tempArray` and append last item to the draggable events list.

```
$('#undo-last-item').click(function() {
    if (Object.entries(tempArray).length > 0) {
        var eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
        eventDiv.setAttribute("class", "fc-event");
        eventDiv.setAttribute("id", tempArray.id);
        eventDiv.setAttribute("date", tempArray.start);
        eventDiv.innerText = tempArray.title;

        $('#external-events-listing').append(eventDiv);

        $(eventDiv).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 0
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', tempArray.id);

        tempArray = [];
    }
});
```

**Full code:** [Drag an external event to calendar's specific date](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/MPpRbJ)

Comment: I still maintain that using drag in any way is confusing to the user. It gives the expectation that they can choose where to place the event, but in this case they cannot. So, while your solution is correct from a technical perspective, in my opinion it's not very user-friendly. Why not handle this via a simple click on the external event? When it clicked, it will be added to the calendar.

Comment: Totally agree with your comment, it's not user-friendly and I would also prefer to use simple click, but if OP has decided to use drag and drop then showing an alert message would be okay as well.

Comment: Personally I think OP has decided to use drag and drop because they haven't properly considered the use case or the alternative approaches. They haven't looked at it from the user's point of view, they've just seen the drag and drop demo on the fullCalendar website and decided to butcher it. An answer using click instead (and explaining why) would be a perfectly good answer, IMHO. Maybe if I have time I'll write one, or you can add it.

Comment: @Adeel what I need is to make editable false and your code works, but then when i try to return back to the list it wont, I thought to add a button on side undo that is it possible with editable false ..? because I dont want event after being dragged to the right slot  to be able to move to other slots after that

Comment: @lilo external button added to revert all events back to the list, but, if you have other events as well on the calendar that you don't want to move to the external list, then add another property something like `type: external` in `var newEvent = {...` and then on `#back-to-list` click, check in `clientEvents` that if **type** is `external` move to draggable events list, otherwise don't!

Comment: Is it possible only the last one that I dragged to undo back to the calendar or only all because I have this case here that I need only the last one or only on click of the event on calendar to be able to go back to list of events.. thank you very much for helping me , maybe I am asking too much but I am new on coding and sometimes I am stuck for days .. :/

Comment: it's alright and yes, it's possible. set global tempArray and add new event in that array while dragging and then on undo button click, retrieve the event details from tempArray.. Check CodePen!

Comment: AND it is also possible to undo only last one by using eventClick function of FullCalendar, so if you use eventClick then you don't need to add external button.. [eventClick FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)